# How to define this hasManyThrough relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following models. `Event` belongs to a `Casefile`. `Casefile` and `User` are many-to-many.

```
class Casefile extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Event', 'casefile');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function casefiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Casefile::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}

class Event extends Model
{
    public function casefile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Casefile');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Casefile');
    }
}
```

When I try to:

```
App\Event::find(526)->users()->get();
```

It gives:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'casefiles.event_id' in 'field
>   list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `casefiles`.`event_id` from `users`
>   inner join `casefiles` on `casefiles`.`id` = `users`.`casefile_id`
>   where `casefiles`.`event_id` = 526)'

How can I define the "`Event` has many `User`s" relation through `Casefile`?

Comment: Is the `morphMany` in the `events` method on the `Casefile` class intentional? It looks wrong and could be causing your error.

Comment: The `morphMany` in `events()` is by design. However, I tried changing that to a `hasMany` and get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use `HasManyThrough` here without a pivot model for the `casefile_user` table.

You can define a `BelongsToMany` relationship instead:

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'casefile_user', 'casefile_id', null, 'casefile_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not followed laravel naming convention for column name. Then you can specify your column name like this

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\User',
            'App\Casefile',
            'event_id', // Foreign key on casefiles table...
            'user_id', // Foreign key on users table...
        );
    }
```

For more [Laravel HasManyThrough Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)